# Glide shows the old loaded images instead of the new

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

Using **Glide** I'm able to load images from URLs, the code below works fine, my only issue is when I scroll `RecylerView` faster, I see the old loaded Images again instead of the original images, after 1 or 2 seconds (depends on the internet connection), everything becomes normal

When I open the app (**Before Scroll**) :

[image]

When I scroll faster (Horizontally) I see the same loaded images but after 1 or 2 seconds images change to the normal state :

[image]

```
   void onBindView(int position) {
        imgframe.setImageBitmap(null);
        final String s = spacecrafts.get(position);
        Glide.with(c).asBitmap().load(s).apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        img.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                        imgframe.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to clear the cache of the device and network from Glide

Comment: I am unable to understand your point can you describe it more specific way?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way RecylerViews work. They get recycled. Before you load the new image, the old one keeps showing... A workaround may be to put a placeholder image immediately, while the new one comes through the network.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, to fix it i used a placeholder.

```
Glide.with(myViewHolder.context).load(myUri).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image).into(myViewHolder.image);
```